# How can I slow down the effect of a surveygizmo navigation button with JavaScript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am trying to slow down a navigation button on surveygizmo. I have a function tied in to the div that when the button used to navigate away from the page is clicked it begins a file upload. The problem is that when the user navigates away if the upload isn't finished then nothing is saved. 
My current code is:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#sg_SubmitButton').click(function(){
     document.VideoRecorder.stopVideo();
     setTimeout(function(){ alert("Navigating away from page"); }, 200);       
   });
});
</script>
```

This section of the code stops a video recorder as well as automatically starts the upload:

```
document.VideoRecorder.stopVideo();
```

I was hoping that by forcing the user to click either an alert or confirm dialog the upload would finish in the background before the page navigated away. However the alert pauses both the navigation and the upload. The maximum amount of time for the upload seems to be about 5 seconds. If I could delay the navigation away and show a countdown or loading symbol that would be perfect.

Comment: None of that really helped me too much or I didn't really understand it. Could I create a new button that initializes the upload then once that is finished activate the navigation button while its hidden?

Comment: What do you mean by navigation. If I click a bookmark or back button or drag a url to the page it will navigate away. If the means of navigation is a button you create, then sure, hide it while submitting.

Comment: Do you have access to the function stopVideo ? That is where you need to hide the button. If that then also has a callback when the video has finished uploading, use that to continue the navigation

Comment: This is all being done on SurveyGizmo where there is a 'Next' button that navigates to the next page of the survey. Unfortunately because this is not my own website but a third-party I do not have complete access for manipulation. What code would I use to make one button 'Click' another button?

Comment: The stop video function is part of an API for the video recorder so I cannot manipulate that either, at least not within my knowledge. Also for some reason    $('sg_SubmitButton').hide()   is not hiding the button either.

Comment: Actually you could. `var oldStop =  document.VideoRecorder.stopVideo; document.VideoRecorder.stopVideo=function() { hideButton();  oldStop(); showButton() }`

Comment: could you explain this? where would I put the code inside of my .click() function? I need to have stopVideo() function to be triggered by something.

Comment: It's quite self explanatory. If you put this script AFTER the loading of the API but BEFORE running, the function in the API is replaced by your function that first does whatever you want it to do, then executes the copy of the original function

Comment: Also do not use a submit button but a type=button

Answer (score 0):

There is a .delay JQuery function that pauses. Takes an argument in milliseconds, I believe. Might be what you're looking for?

Comment: This is a comment. You have enough rep to write an actual comment so please do. .delay will not stop navigation